# Yii2 Add math in where condition

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

In users table I have a column call "month".

I want to list all users that meet the condition: **current month - user month <=2**

Here my code

```
$time = new \DateTime('now');
$today = $time->format('m');
$users = Users::find()->where(['<=', 'month' - $today, 2])->all();
```

But this code is wrong. Please help me with this.

Hope this all make sense.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you subtracting integer from string here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Yii2 you can use different format for buil where condition 
for this kind of situatio is useful use string format with param

in string format you can pass the literal string and param this way

```
$users = Users::find()->where('(month - :today ) <= 2' , [':today'=>$today])->all();
```

see this for more http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#where()-detail